# can't compile due to "non-static class Item cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java

Error message when i run `javac ResizingArrayStack.java`

```
$ javac ResizingArrayStack.java 
ResizingArrayStack.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class item
location: class ResizingArrayStack<Item>
  private class ReverseArrayIterator implements Iterator<item> {
                                                         ^
ResizingArrayStack.java:53: non-static class Item cannot be referenced from a static context
    ResizingArrayStack<Item> s;
                       ^
ResizingArrayStack.java:54: non-static class Item cannot be referenced from a static context
    s = new ResizingArrayStack<Item>();
                               ^
Note: ResizingArrayStack.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
```

Code

```
import java.util.Iterator;
public class ResizingArrayStack<Item> implements Iterable<Item>
{
  private Item[] a = (Item[]) new Object[1];
  private int N = 0;

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return N == 0;
  }

  public int size() {
    return N;
  }

  private void resize(int max) {
    Item[] temp = (Item[]) new Object[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      temp[i] = a[i];
    }
    a = temp;
  }

  public void push(Item item) {
    if (N == a.length) resize(2*a.length);
    a[N++] = item;
  }

  public Item pop() {
    Item item = a[--N];
    a[N] = null;
    if (N > 0 && N == a.length/4) resize(a.length/2);
    return item;
  }

  public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    return new ReverseArrayIterator(); 
  }

  private class ReverseArrayIterator implements Iterator<item> {
    private int i = N;
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return i > 0;
    }
    public Item next() {
      return a[--i];
    }
    public void remove() {

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResizingArrayStack<Item> s;
    s = new ResizingArrayStack<Item>();
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
      String item = StdIn.readString();
      if (!item.equals("-")) {
        s.push(item);
      }
      else if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        StdOut.print(s.pop() + " ");
      }

      StdOut.println("(" + s.size() + " left on stack");
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why the compile errors are happening?

Comment: And that's a good thing!  (`main` is a `static` method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. First, you seem to have a typo

```
 private class ReverseArrayIterator implements Iterator<item> { 
                                                        ^
```

Second, the use of `Item` in

```
public class ResizingArrayStack<Item> implements Iterable<Item>
```

is declaring a new type variable with the name `Item`. It is equivalent to

```
public class ResizingArrayStack<T> implements Iterable<T>
```

If you meant to use it as a type argument for `Iterable`, use it like so

```
public class ResizingArrayStack implements Iterable<Item>
```

Third, I don't know where the type `Item` used here

```
ResizingArrayStack<Item> s;
```

is declared, but it seems to be in an inner class. An inner class requires an instance of the outer class. It therefore can't be accessed from a `static` context.

Answer (score -1):

You really need to work on your Java, it is pretty clear you come from a different language. Here is the fixed code that will help you further your understanding. This isn't the complete answer but it should be more than enough to explain what is wrong with your code.

There is no need to have a generic of `Item` if you're just going to cast it to an `Object`.

```
public class ResizingArrayStack implements Iterable<Object>
{
    private Object[] a = new Object[1];
    private int N = 0;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    private void resize(int max) {
        Object[] temp = new Object[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            temp[i] = a[i];
        }
        a = temp;
    }

    public void push(Object item) {
        if (N == a.length) resize(2*a.length);
        a[N++] = item;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        Object item = a[--N];
        a[N] = null;
        if (N > 0 && N == a.length/4) resize(a.length/2);
        return item;
    }

    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new ReverseArrayIterator();
    }

    private class ReverseArrayIterator implements Iterator<Object> {
        private int i = N;
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i > 0;
        }
        public Object next() {
            return a[--i];
        }
        public void remove() {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResizingArrayStack s;
        s = new ResizingArrayStack();
        for (;;) {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String item = scanner.nextLine();
                if (scanner.nextLine() != null) {
                    if (!item.equals("-")) {
                        s.push(item);
                    }
                    else if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println(s.pop() + " ");
                    }
                }

                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the point of the `Object[]`. You can't instantiate generic type arrays so you need the `Object[]`. Also, providing code doesn't explain much, especially if you refactored everything.